# Using grok in flink streaming

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, grok, flink-streaming

Flink Pipeline is as follows:

1. read messages(string) from kafka topic.
2. pattern matching through grok converting to json format.
3. Aggregations over a time window over extracted field from json.

Below is the code for pattern matching using grok.

```
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<JSONObject> mainStream = messageStream.rebalance()
                    .map(new MapFunction<String, JSONObject>() {    
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6;
                        
                        @Override
                        public JSONObject map(String value) throws Exception {
                            JSONObject logJson = new JSONObject();  
                            grok.compile(pattern); //pattern is some pattern defined in the class
                            Match gm = grok.match(value);
                            gm.captures();
                            logJson.putAll(gm.toMap());
                            return logJson;
                        }})
```

In the above code writing `grok.compile(pattern)` inside the map function works fine. Not doing so gives the following error

> The implementation of the MapFunction is not serializable
>
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.code.regexp.Pattern

Is there any way in which I could remove the **grok.compile** outside the map. As per my understanding the compilation of the pattern with every message is not required and might create a bottleneck if the no. of messages becomes quite large.

PS: I have imported  the package  oi.thekraken.grok.api.Grok

**EDIT:**

I looked through grok implementation and the Grok class implements Serializable.
https://github.com/thekrakken/java-grok/blob/master/src/main/java/io/thekraken/grok/api/Grok.java

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not show where the local variable grok comes from, but:

Flink requires all operators to be Serializable because they might be moved around in a cluster. This also holds true for all members of operators. Can you post a complete non-working example? This might make it easier to see where serialization might fail.

More information about flink serialization can be ound in the flink documentation at 
https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-nonserializableexception- and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/types_serialization.html

Basically, you can register a kryo serializer for custom types or implement (de-)serialization yourself if you need operator members that are not directly serializable.

Btw.: I think you are right in trying to reduce the number of times the pattern is compiled

Comment: `Basically, you can register a kryo serializer for custom types or implement (de-)serialization yourself if you need operator members that are not directly serializable.` --- I am little confused on how to do the same .